# Bar chart in Latex

Tags: bar-chart

I am trying to write the code for the following bar chart.
[image]
So far, I can only do this: 
[image]
As you can see, I failed to produce the legends similar to the original chart. The legend in the original chart is right next to each chart. 
I would very appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you in advance.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar, 
    bar width=0.2cm,
    %enlarge x limits=0.25,
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    tick align=inside,
    major grid style={draw=black},
    %enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    %axis x line*=bottom,
    %axis y line*=right,
    %hide y axis,axis line style={shorten >=-15pt, shorten <=-15pt},
    symbolic y coords={1990-1997, 1998-1999, 2000-2008},
    %ytick=data,
                legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.01)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
    %nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta} }
]
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=blue!30] coordinates {
        (75.4064,1990-1997)
        (72.7961,1998-1999) 
        (94.4597,2000-2008) };
    \addplot [draw=none,fill=red!30] coordinates {
        (5.4064,1990-1997)
        (89.7961,1998-1999) 
        (94.4597,2000-2008) };
       \node [left] at (0,5) {D}; 
    \legend{blue, red}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Try `xbar=0pt`.

Comment: It should remove the space between the bars.